# How to sum of rows with time format(00:00:00) and produce in footer of Grid View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

As am a beginner in .Net, am confusing with one of my question. 
The thing is, am having a content in one column as 8:7:15, 9:15:12,and 10:3:4. 
My question is, How to add these three rows and produce in footer of Grid view as 27:25:31. I know to make of sum of rows but am stuck with this type of format.

Any help would be more helpful to me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this `8:7:15` time or something else and what is the logic behind adding these.

Comment: Yeah, its time of employee working hours. The first employee named as A, he worked for three days.First day he worked for 8 hours : 7 minutes: 15 seconds, like this for all days he worked. And my question is I need to calculate total hours worked by this employee.

Comment: Could you understand my question?, It's urgent now, so please help me to come out from this confusion.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gkrishy, Check my answer and let me know if you have any suggestions. Please mark as answer if its fine to you.

Comment: +1 for good logical question !

Comment: Tvalue1 = (Convert.ToInt32(Tvalue1.Remove(Tvalue1.Length - 1)) + Convert.ToInt32(cx[0])) + ":".ToString();    Here am getting error as "Input string is not in correct format"...Can you suggest the error ?.@Ramesh Rajendran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assign three column value return your sql query and that values are assigned three string , Now we can calculate that values for your requirement , see below

```
        string x1 = "8:7:15";//1st column value
        string x2 = "9:15:12";//2ndcolumn value
        string x3 = "10:3:4";//3rd column value
        string[] Cx1 = x1.Split(':');
        string[] Cx2 = x2.Split(':');
        string[] Cx3 = x3.Split(':');
        string Tx1 = ((Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx2[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx3[0])) + ":" + (Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[1])
            + Convert.ToInt32(Cx2[1]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx3[1]))) + ":" + (Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[2]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx2[2]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx3[2])).ToString();
```

> Finally you can give this Tx1 value to your footer cell .

**Update**

```
            string x1 = "8:7:15";//1st column value
            string x2 = "9:15:12";//2ndcolumn value
            string x3 = "10:3:4";//3rd column value
            string x4 = "1:1:1";
            string x5 = "1:1:1";

    // , I just assign 5 values,but you can assign more than lot values  in this array 
            string[] xxA = new string[5];
            xxA[0] = x1;
            xxA[1] = x2;
            xxA[2] = x3;
            xxA[3] = x4;
            xxA[4] = x5;


            string Tvalue1 = "0";
            string Tvalue2 = "0";
            string Tvalue3 = "0";
      //Now the xxA has 5 rows (No problem for how many rows ) So this foreach will round 5 time 

            for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)//Now xxA.Length is 5
            {
               string x = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].ToString();
               int n=GridView1.Rows.Count;
               string[] xxA=new string[n]; 
                xxA[i] = x; 
      //Here is the some logic's for the calculation and formating  
                string[] Cx1 = xxA[i].Split(':');
                Tvalue1 = (Convert.ToInt32(Tvalue1) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[0])).ToString() ;
                Tvalue2 = (Convert.ToInt32(Tvalue2) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[1])).ToString() ;
                Tvalue3 = (Convert.ToInt32(Tvalue3) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[2])).ToString();
            }
            string FInalValue = Tvalue1 +":"+ Tvalue2 + ":"+ Tvalue3;
```

Now you can get the total formating values in FInalValue  variable.

**Final code**:

```
        string Tvalue1 = "0";
        string Tvalue2 = "0";
        string Tvalue3 = "0";
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)//here 3 is gridview row length
    {
        string x = "1:1:1";//This your cell value
        int n = 3;
        string[] xxA = new string[n];
        xxA[i] = x;
        //Here is the some logic's for the calculation and formating  
        string[] Cx1 = xxA[i].Split(':');
        Tvalue1 = (Convert.ToInt32(Tvalue1) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[0])).ToString();
        Tvalue2 = (Convert.ToInt32(Tvalue2) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[1])).ToString();
        Tvalue3 = (Convert.ToInt32(Tvalue3) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[2])).ToString();
    }
    string FInalValue = Tvalue1 + ":" + Tvalue2 + ":" + Tvalue3;
```

See this [Demo](http://ideone.com/gkBeHa) :

Comment: Thanks for your response, in case of Multiple column values. for eg: As i mentioned above, Employee named A working on several days(not for three days), how can i calculate at this situation?....

Comment: Use foreach and give the values to the string by foreach count !

Comment: Am not getting the answer correctly. When i use for condition,am stuck in this line,                string Tx1 = ((Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx2[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx3[0])) + ":" + (Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[1])
            + Convert.ToInt32(Cx2[1]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx3[1]))) + ":" + (Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[2]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx2[2]) + Convert.ToInt32(Cx3[2])).ToString();

Comment: Yeah am clear now, really thanks for your effort...!

Comment: Tvalue1 = (Convert.ToInt32(Tvalue1.Remove(Tvalue1.Length - 1)) + Convert.ToInt32(cx[0])) + ":".ToString();    Here am getting error as "Input string is not in correct format"...Can you suggest the error ?.@Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: Did you set `string Tvalue1 = "00";` on top side ?

Comment: This error mean is your input value is not correct format , You give some string value for any one of the value, only integer values are allowed for add  calculation , so check if the array value have any string value ,if yes,remove that .Check the code with break point !

Comment: To get multiple column values, I changed ur coding as     for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            string x = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].ToString();
            int n=GridView1.Rows.Count;
            string[] xx=new string[n];
            xx[i] = x;    and then I declared values for Tvalue 1,2 and 3.After this I moved with for(as per ur coding remaining left)

Comment: No , You need to declare this values in above for loop, must declare the 

Tvalue 1,2 and 3 values in top of the for loop !

Comment: And i gave some idea for the below answer .I comment for the other answer problem in that answer . and you check out that !!

Comment: I used two for loops in my code, and as per your words. I changed string Tvalue 1, 2 & 3 to above of first for loop. But still am getting the same error..."Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: Did you check my sample codes are working to you ? and wait i will change your code .

Comment: Okay , If my answer will helps to you,The put up vote and markusanswer !!

Comment: Yea i changed my code and executed.But still am getting the "Input string was not in correct format" error.

Comment: Have you check with used breakpoints ?  Check Tvalue1 value and Cx1[0]; And this `string Tvalue1 = "00";` should be need two zero(00) ,Not a one zero(0) !

Comment: As I said am a beginner here, I dont know to execute with break points. And "00" only I used for my string Tvalue.

Comment: Okay , Let see one more time my Update code, Now i totally changed that !

Comment: hmm !! The Cx1[0] values are correct ? You know the correct value ? and the format should be like `11:11:11`  can't add any spaces and other characters , and please use `Cx1[0].Trim()` in there , like ` Convert.ToInt32(Cx1[0].Trim()))` , My codes are proper working to me , Now am checked ,It's working perfect, did you check for anything missed

Comment: Yeah values are correct, and I added .trim() as you said, but the same remains(Input string error in run time)

Comment: no I didn't missed anything as per my knowledge. But these are high compare to my knowledge. So I may be missed anything as you saying.

Comment: Look my Final code , It's working good for me , and you should be add this code in inside of gridview row databound .

Comment: yaeh same things are only there in my code..But I dont know why the same error is repeating again...!. As u saying, I may be missed anything.Really thanks for your guidance and response, as a beginner i learned some thing because of you @Ramesh Rajendran.

Comment: I guess the error , I think you does not put my code in inside of the `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)` condition , My code will should be put inside of `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {//code here
}` in Gridview Row-Databound event.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I got the solution. Its a rock breaking effort. Thank you @Ramesh Rajendran

Answer (score 2):

You may try a code like following. Use the Gridview Row-Databound event.
Inside the Row-Databound event, calculate the total time by splitting the string in individual components like I have shown below.

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        string[] empTotalTime = new string[3] { "0", "0", "0" };
        for (int counter = 0; counter < gv.Rows.Count; counter++)
        {
            string[] singleTime = gv.Rows[counter].Cells["Your Column Index"].Text.Split(':');
            empTotalTime[0] = (Convert.ToInt32(empTotalTime[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(singleTime[0])).ToString();
            empTotalTime[1] = (Convert.ToInt32(empTotalTime[1]) + Convert.ToInt32(singleTime[1])).ToString();
            empTotalTime[2] = (Convert.ToInt32(empTotalTime[2]) + Convert.ToInt32(singleTime[2])).ToString();
        }
        ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalTime")).Text = empTotalTime[0] +":" + empTotalTime[1] + ":" + empTotalTime[2];
    }
```

Comment: How could use this, In case of multiple column values instead of three column records.

Comment: Its very easy. The Gridview Row Databoud event is going to fire for each and every row. Inside it you can run a loop for each column of the gridview and then do the necessary addition.

Comment: +1. I think this is for good answer + Helps to calculate more columns value

Comment: Yeah i tried this too...Thanks for your help..Now am pressure free...:-)

Comment: @user1039119. When am using your procedure, it is adding like this...Ex-0:2:0 and 0:5:0, now the result is 0:25:0....But I need the result as 0:7:0....Where I did mistake?...

Comment: He need to Convert.toString for `singleTime[0]` and `singleTime[1]` and `singleTime[2]`

Comment: I used .tostring() for singletime[0],[1] and [2]. But the result is same as i mentioned above....

Comment: Don't need to.String . You need to change `Convert.ToInt32(singleTime[0])` instead of `singleTime[0]` , Same as `singleTime[1]` and `singleTime[2]`

Comment: Already convert.toint32(singleTime[0]) is mentioned in his coding. Just watch it clearly. He used a close bracket for common...!

Comment: Hey not a common man !! Did you tried that ? `Convert.ToInt32(empTotalTime[0])` Now this code converted in *empTotalTime[0]* only , not a **singleTime[0]** , So it's  will go to  string concatenation, !!

Comment: Now I changed my coding like this,    'empTotalTime[0] = (Convert.ToInt32(empTotalTime[0])) + (Convert.ToInt32(singleTime[0])).ToString();'    .But the same problem remains. It is not adding.

Comment: Nope , You have add extra brackets in your code , I mean that code look like : `empTotalTime[0] = (Convert.ToInt32(empTotalTime[0]) + Convert.ToInt32(singleTime[0])).ToString();` , try this code instead of that code !

Comment: @user1039119 , You are totally wrong, I already edit your code,But your not approved that and your not changed that issue. Why ? Your code is wrong for the OP question, So please change your code by my advice, thanks, It's helping to others !!

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran Hey you are effort are really great...Its working now in this code.

Comment: hmm !! But my code are working to me !! i think you missed anything !